# Insert Into statement stuck in loop

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I have two tables Table1 and Table2, and I am trying to insert all data from Table1 into Table2. To do this, I have an Insert Into statement, which inserts in batches, as shown below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_table_data @tp_int INT AS
DECLARE @rc INT
SET @rc = 1
WHILE @rc > 0
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO table_2(
    col1,
    col2,
    time_period
    )
    SELECT TOP (500) col1, col2, @tp_int FROM table_1
    DELETE TOP (500) FROM table_1
    SET @rc = @@ROWCOUNT
    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
```

I would ideally like to do this without using a Delete statement. When I do take out the delete statement, the stored procs gets stuck in a loop. I am guessing this is because it keeps picking the Top(500) from table_1, without progressing further down the records. Any ideas on how to modify the stored procs?

Comment: Yes coz you @rc count will always be more than 1 based on top 500.. you need to have an ending point after each insert  and to restrict the loop based on some max value or some where condition (for which you don't need loop)

Comment: I don't have any sort of keys or unique id's in the data, it's from an external vendor. what else could I use to restrict the loop?

Comment: then you don't need loop right ? you can just remove the loop condition.. you would need loop unless you want it to evaluate based on some condition or updating based on some org ids or something like that

Comment: but I want to insert in batches. the amount of data being transferred is going to be millions of rows, so doing a simple insert into statement would be undesirable

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to delete along the way I would consider using an OFFSET/FETCH type of query.  Clearly performance will start to drop the farther you have to read into your table, but I would test it out and consider how to use an index to help out.

And if you are moving millions of rows, I would step that batch size up a little bit.

```
DECLARE @batchsize INT
DECLARE @start INT
DECLARE @numberofrows INT

SELECT @numberofrows = COUNT(*) from table_1

SET @batchsize = 500
SET @start = 1

WHILE @start < @numberofrows
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO table_2(col1,col2,time_period)
        SELECT  col1, col2, @tp_int 
        FROM table_1
            ORDER BY time_period,col1,col2
                OFFSET @start ROWS
                FETCH NEXT @batchsize ROWS ONLY

    SET @start += @batchsize + 1

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END
```